# For linear operator $T(t)$, what is the difference between "$T(t)$ is continuous", "$t\to T(t)$ is continuous", and "$t\mapsto T(t)$"?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, terminology

Let $T(t)$ be a family of linear operators defined on a vector space $X$, $t\geq 0$. What is the difference between the following statements:

1. $T(t)$ is continuous
2. $t\rightarrow T(t)$ is continuous
3. $t\mapsto T(t)$

Comment: Actually you should also precise where does $T$ "arrives", since we cannot know yet what kind of object $T(t)$ is.

Comment: The topic is about uniformly continuous semigroups of bounded linear operators. T is defined as a bounded linear operator from X into X, where X is a Banach space.

Comment: Well it depends, then ! If $X$ is a space of functions, or of operators, it has sense to say that $T(t)$ is continuous. If the elements of $X$ are not functions, then it has no sense...

Comment: Yes, the vector space X should be defined for functions because the operators will be used to analyze partial differential equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $T(t)$ is a family of linear operators parameterized by $t$, we can re-phrase mathematically as $T:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow\mathcal{L}(X)$ (this is what $(3)$ is saying, actually).

$(1)$ means that, for a given $t$, $T(t)\in \mathcal{L}(X)$ is a continuous linear operator. $(2)$ is bad notation and is likely supposed to be $\mapsto$ instead of $\rightarrow$. The latter notation is the notation used to define functions between given sets, not an assignment of a parameter to an output value (which is what the former does). $(3)$ means that $T$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $\mathcal{L}(X).$ That is, you input $t\in\mathbb{R}_+$ and get back a linear operator $T(t)$. So, it's actually the same thing as saying that $T(t)$ is a family of linear operators. If we fix the notation in $(2)$, then $(2)$ means that $T$ as a map from $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $\mathcal{L}(X)$ is continuous. That is, if we fix the notation, then $(2)$ is the same as $(3)$ with the  additional stipulation of continuity of the parameterization.

Answer (score 1):

Just saying “$T(t)$ is continuous” might not make sense unless $T(t)$ is a continuous function. However, saying “$T : X \to X$ is continuous” or “$t \mapsto T(t)$ is continuous makes sense. Keep in mind the arrow $\to$ Is used to show the domain and codomain of $T$, while $\mapsto$ is used to show how $T$ is defined.

Comment: "$T(t)$ is continuous" may have no sense, if $T(t)$ is not a function or an operator.

Comment: With this edit, this is more clear, thank you :)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe - Of course, thank you for your feedback! take a look now and see if that’s any better (:.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "$T(t)$ is continuous" is an abuse of notation as $T(t)$ is the value of the operator $T$ in the point $t\in X$ (unless $T(t)$ is an element in a space of maps). On the other hand, "$t\mapsto T(t)$" can be read as "the map who sends $t$ to $T(t)$". Finally, I wouldn't use the arrow "$\rightarrow$" in the way you have done; in general, "$A\to B$" means "a maps which send each element in the set $A$ to an element of $B$.

Comment: Actually, $t$ is a parameter of the operator and not an element of X.

Comment: In that case, I would say that "$T(t)$ is continuous" means that the operator $T(t):X\to Y$ corresponding to the value $t$ of the parameter is continuous; while $t\mapsto T(t)$ means that the parametrization is continuous, i.e., the map $t\mapsto T(t)$ from the space of parameters  to the space of operators is continuous.